# How the chatbot sends the first auto message after user connects with the Sandbox

Tags: ruby, twilio

I'm trying to develop a beginner chatbot that populates a spotify playlist with songs people add through Whatsapp, but I want when the person sends the first message to connect with the sandbox it receives the bot auto message teaching how to add songs to the playlist.

The chatbot is live, if you want to understand better you can go to the frontend and follow the chatbot flow: https://hellz-i-fy.herokuapp.com/

The code that creates the messages is as follows (PS: I'm using twilio):

```
class Twilio::MessagesController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def create
    body = params['Body']
    spotify = Spotify.new(ENV['SPOTIFY_USER_ID'], ENV['SPOTIFY_TOKEN'], ENV['SPOTIFY_REFRESH_TOKEN'])

    # if ['oi', 'olá', 'ola', '.', 'hi', 'hey', 'eae', 'eai', 'salve'].include? answer
    #   message = "Digite o nome da música seguido do artista para adicioná-la à playlist. _*Ex.: Bad Michael Jackson*_"

    if session[:track]
      answer = body.split(' ').first.downcase.strip
      if ['yes', 'yeah', 'yep', 'yup', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'sim', 's', 'ss', 'com certeza', 'claro'].include? answer
          message = "OK, Adicionando sua música à playlist agora. Acesse a playlist aqui: https://open.spotify.com/playlist/7qdUS3dh2mQy65DTfHlZiP?si=3b866e7162b44aa0"
          spotify.add_to_playlist(ENV['SPOTIFY_PLAYLIST_ID'], session[:track])
          session[:track] = nil
      elsif ['no', 'nah', 'nope', '', ' ', '', '', '', '', 'não', 'n', 'nn', 'de jeito nenhum', 'nah', 'nem', 'sai fora'].include? answer
          session[:track] = nil
          message = "Qual música você gostaria de adicionar?"
      end
    end

    if !message
      track = spotify.track_search(body)
      if track
        session[:track] = track.uri
        message = "Gostaria de adicionar a música _*#{track.name}*_ de _*#{track.artists.map(&:name).to_sentence}*_?"
      else
        message = "Não consegui achar nenhuma música ao pesquisar por '#{body}'. Tente de outra forma."
      end
    end

    response = Twilio::TwiML::MessagingResponse.new
    response.message(body: message)
    render xml: response.to_xml
  end    
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [Twilio Sandbox for using the WhatsApp API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/sandbox) is a testing tool that allows Twilio users to share one WhatsApp number to do initial testing with. It is not intended for production use, therefore in production there is no "add to sandbox" event that you can use to send a welcome message.

Instead, you either need to get your user to send an initial message. Or you can get them to enter their WhatsApp number in your application and opt in to receiving messages, then [send them a template message](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/tutorial/send-whatsapp-notification-messages-templates) as a welcome.